# NUnit: Assert collection has item with specific property value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit

I'm using NUnit to assert that a service is properly added to the `IServiceCollection` in ASP.Net core.

I'm trying to make sure the servicecollection has one `ServiceDescriptor` with ServiceType of type `MyClass`. How would I rewrite this assertion in NUnit syntax?

```
IServiceCollection collection = ...;
Assert.NotNull(collection.SingleOrDefault(sd => sd.ServiceType == typeof(MyService)));
```

I assume it would look something like this:

```
Assert.That(collection, Has.One.?????);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```cs
Assert.That(collection, Has.One.With.Property("ServiceType").EqualTo(typeof(MyService)));
```

The "With" is optional but seems to make it read better.

Comment: Thanks. Would have been great if the 'Property' method could do this: `.Property(sd => sd.ServiceType)`

Comment: Yup, that has been a longstanding enhancement request.

Comment: Not so bad if you use `nameof`.